# Where are the images stored that are being shown in my screen saver?

Tags: macos, screensaver, file-location

I'm not really familiar with Mac at all, but I have a friend who has this issue (she's a mac person, but not a computer person), so thought I would give it a shot.

The problem is that she has some old pictures that show up in her screensaver rotation - she really wants to save them/back them up, but we don't seem to be able to find them on her computer.

They aren't in iPhoto, and a search for all images on her box doesn't turn them up.

Looking at the system properties for the screensaver slideshow, you can see a listing of the pics, but there is no way to tell where they are stored (at least that I could find).  Click and double click just open it in a little window, I can't right click with her mouse, and I tried all the symbol-clicks I could see on the keyboard - no love.

Can anyone tell me where the pics in the screensaver rotation are stored, and why they might not show up in a full computer search for all images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the folder is given in *System Preferences » Desktop & Screen Saver » Screen Saver*. If that is not enough to locate it, you have two options:

1. Decode the encoded data specifying where on the file system the folder is located
2. Monitor file system accesses while images from that folder are displayed.

### Decode the data

The location is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.*.plist`, `*` being a UUID.

Now run the following command in Terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print moduleDict:fileRef' $( ls -t ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.*.plist | grep -v slideshow | head -n1 ) | grep -oaE 'file://[^[:cntrl:]]+/'
```

This will first get the most recent `com.apple.screensaver.*.plist` file that does not contain `slideshow` in its name and read its contents: the relevant entry of the property list file is `moduleDict:fileRef`.

Now the return value (much binary data) is filtered for a file URL. This is printed. On my system, it looks like this:

```
file:///Users/danielbeck/Pictures/
```

The path, of course, is `/Users/danielbeck/Pictures`.

### Monitor the file system

Open *System Preferences » Desktop & Screen Saver » Screen Saver* and select the folder you want to locate to see a preview.

Now, while leaving this window open, open a Terminal window and run the following:

```
sudo opensnoop | grep -v '/.vol' | grep "System Pref"
```

Enter your password, and wait. It will print the paths to the image files as they are loaded (when one file is being displayed, the next one is already loaded). Some of the files that are listed are *false positives*, but they should be easy to recognize:

```
501  77313 System Preferen  16 /Users/danielbeck/Pictures/Icons/fugue-icons-2.0/icon/contrast-small.png 
501  77313 System Preferen  16 /Users/danielbeck/Pictures/Icons/Crystal Clear/22x22/actions/ok.png 
501  77313 System Preferen  16 /System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc 
501  77313 System Preferen  16 /Users/danielbeck/Pictures/Icons/GNU Lesser General Public License/nuvola/64x64/mimetypes/tgz.png 
501  77313 System Preferen  16 /Users/danielbeck/Pictures/Icons/crystal_project/32x32/devices/pipe.png
```

Use this to locate the path to the pictures folder.

Comment: Or fseventer, if that's easier ;)

Comment: @slhck One-liner in bash! `osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to { activate, display dialog \"$( echo -e "$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print moduleDict:fileRef' $( ls -t ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.*.plist | grep -v slideshow | head -n1 ) | grep -oaE 'file://[^[:cntrl:]]+/' | sed 's/+/ /g; s/%/\\x/g' )" | cut -c8- )\" }" 2>/dev/null || true`

Comment: @DanielBeck - Thanks very much for sharing the `opensnoop` method. Worked instantly in OS X 10.9 and 10.10, and in 10.11 after disabling SIP (Recovery Mode > Terminal > `csrutil disable; reboot`).

Answer (score 0):

Not being command line savvy, I used a smart folder which is a user-friendly GUI way of searching for files on Mac storage. Since this included many pictures from my daughter's wedding, my two search rules were "Created date"  "after" the day before the wedding, and "Kind" is "Image" "JPEG". This narrowed my search to one folder. Additionally, I set my file view to Icon, which gave me thumbnails of the photos for easy verification.

It is easy to use a smart folder. Try it: https://support.apple.com/en-kg/guide/mac-help/mchlp2804/mac